# In PostgreSQL dump/restore, auto incremental sequences duplicate violation constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints, restore, dump

I found a funny bug, important a postgresql dump file with psql:

In case if your table has a `sequence(auto increment field)`, for example before import nextvalue of sequence was 10, after the import we add 100 lines and logically nextvalue must be 111. *But it is still 11*, and of course you will have a constraint violation on the next insert.

The workaround:

1. get current next value with a `select nextval('xxx_seq')`
2. `select max(xxx_id) from yyyy`

It is give you the max current value of autoincrement id.

Now we need to set the next value to 2) + 1:

```
SELECT setval('xxx_seq', n+1, true)
```

Dump into a file:

```
pg_dump --data-only -h host -p port -U username -a  dbname > outputfilename
```

Restoring the dump:

```
psql -h host -U username dbname < outputfilename
```

I use the db version 9.5.5 .

Comment: 1. Good start. 2. Note, it would be important to make your question so comprehensible as you can. Formatting is important. Also grammar is important. 3. Please break up your post into a question/answer form. It is needed because reading your post, the googlers of the future want here a question.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: it's not a bug.

Tables are linked to sequences by the fact that columns may have `nextval(sequence_name)` as their default value.

A default clause means that when the value is already provided by the INSERT or a COPY, this `nextval(...)` expression is not evaluated and the sequence is not incremented. That is what happens when you play a dump.

In the general case, such columns are created as `SERIAL` and the dump files contain `setval` of corresponding sequences to adjust them afte the  load. Your case differs in how you created the tables or what options were passed to `pg_dump`, but these details don't appear in the question.